# Trying to check if a character is present in a string and return False if it is

Tags: python, function

Creating a "Password" type function. Can someone help me understand why this is printing True for the last function call when it should be printing False?

```
def product_code_check(string):
    forbidden_c = ["!@#$%^&*(){}|[]\:;'?/<>,.`~"]
    no_space = " "
    if len(string) >= 8:
        for i in string:
            if i in no_space:
                return False
            elif i in forbidden_c:
                return False
            elif not any(i.isupper() for i in string):
                return False
            elif not any(i.islower() for i in string):
                return False
            elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in string):
                return False
            else:
                return True
    else:
        return False

print(product_code_check("g00dlONGproductCODE"))
print(product_code_check("fRV53FwSXX663cCd"))
print(product_code_check("2shOrt"))
print(product_code_check("alll0wercase"))
print(product_code_check("inv4l1d CH4R4CTERS~"))
```

it should be outputting

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

Comment: You're only checking the first character of the string.

Comment: Since you `return True` if none of the `if` conditions succeeds for the character.

Comment: Take `return True` out of the loop.

Comment: Note that since ``forbidden_c`` is a list of a string of characters and ``i`` is a single character, ``i in forbidden_c:`` can never be true.

Comment: You should ``return True`` *after* the loop, not *inside* the loop.

Comment: I saw that as well, thank you. Your comment and Barmars made me take a closer look to try and understand. Much appreciate the help from you both. I posted an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed list brackets turning it into a string, as well as pulling the return True out of the loop. Added continue to the else statement so if it did not satisfy any aspects of the loop it tried again with the next character of the string.

function now outputs:

```
True
True
False
False
False
```

and operates correctly.

code:

```
def product_code_check(string):
    forbidden_c = "!@#$%^&*(){}|[]\:;'?/<>,.`~"
    no_space = " "
    if len(string) >= 8:
        for i in string:
            if i in no_space:
                return False
            elif i in forbidden_c:
                return False
            elif not any(i.isupper() for i in string):
                return False
            elif not any(i.islower() for i in string):
                return False
            elif not any(i.isdigit() for i in string):
                return False
            else:
                continue
        return True
    else:
        return False
```